# Need a silverlight control show Multiselect options

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have an Silverlight application.

I wanted a way to show multiselect options to users and was thinking if we had something which I can use out of the box.

One way of doing it, I thought was creating a custom control - Multi-Select combo box.
Any better ways of doing it?

Regards,
Bhavik

Answer (score 0):

you could put your data in a standard ListBox and set SelectionMode="Multiple", maybe only show one item at a time, and have a button on the side control the height of your visible items. like this:

XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="1166" Height="400">
    <ListBox x:Name="myList" SelectionMode="Multiple" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="100" Height="24">
        <TextBlock Text="Item 1" Height="22"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Item 2" Height="22"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Item 3" Height="22"/>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="Drop" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="0" Click="Button_Click" />
</Canvas>
```

C#:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myList.Height == 24)
        {
            myList.Height = 100;
        }
        else
        {
            myList.Height = 24;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems liked hacked. I wanted something out of the box.. Some control which can be used as-is.